# Cython: unexpected type int_t and base type tuple object for indexing

Tags: segmentation-fault, cython, cythonize

I'm compiling a cython module, which throws a `SIGSEGV` error on application runtime.
After setting `boundscheck=False` in the compiler directives, I can't compile (cythonize) anymore and get a long stack trace which does not point to my own code:

```
warning: cpc_naive/cythonCode.pyx:319:27: Index should be typed for more efficient access
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pdiracdelta/Documents/UHasselt/PRiSM/src/CPC-naive/setup.py", line 48, in <module>
    ext_modules=cythonize(ext_modules, compiler_directives=compiler_directives),
  File "/home/pdiracdelta/.conda/envs/prism/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 1101, in cythonize
  ...
  File "/home/pdiracdelta/.conda/envs/prism/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/ExprNodes.py", line 4029, in generate_result_code
    self.type, self.base.type)
AssertionError: unexpected type int_t and base type tuple object for indexing
```

How do I even begin debugging this? At first I had tuples doing 2-level indexing on 2D arrays like so:

```
cdef double[:,:] my2darray
tuple mytuple
my2darray = np.zeros(shape=(3,3))
mytuple = (1,2)
print(my2darray[mytuple])
```

but I unraveled all of them like so (I actually already did this earlier because they would throw a `CompileError` saying `Cannot assign type 'double[:]' to 'double'`):

```
print(my2darray[mytuple[0], mytuple[1]])
```

and I still get the same `AssertionError` message. What's going on? How can I properly debug this?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I'm pretty sure you have to unpack the tuple and can't use it to index memoryviews, but I just get `TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer` at runtime, with or without boundchecking. (The exact code you provide has a syntax error anywhere, so it needs modifying before I can even start to try reproducing it)

Comment: @DavidW hmm sorry about the syntax error - this is a mockup and my actual code is long and sort of proprietary... But maybe you have some idea about how to properly debug a scenario where there is a CompileError?

Comment: "With difficulty" I think unfortunately. You can sometimes look at the Cython source around the error/insert a `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` breakpoint in it to try to understand why you've ended up there. Although in practice the problem is usually quite a bit earlier so that doesn't always help. If you have a segmentation fault then compiling it with `CFLAGS=-Og setup.py etc...` and running it in gdb can sometimes be helpful, but you can end looking at barely readable generated code.